# gitorious gives permission denied on fresh bitnami setup , amazon ec2 instance using https

Tags: ssl, apache2, bitnami, gitorious

This is a brand new installation of a bitnami gitorius image on EC2, worked fine until i tried to enable https/ssl.

I am sure i have misconfigured apache somehow, however the root document at https://tarantula.anatexis.net loads just fine.

but if one goes to the gitorious app at [https://tarantula.anatexis.net/gitorious](https://tarantula.anatexis.net/gitorious/) you get permission denied.

which config file do I edit to allow https traffic to gitorious.

looking at the apache logs, is see this,

```
[Mon Jun 03 17:25:20 2013] [error] [client 71.17.13.29] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/gitorious/, referer:Https://tarantula.anatexis.net/
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i fixed it, found the file  /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf   this config file has the document root in it for ssl  traffic, the default is wrong and it needs to be changed to

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/gitorious/htdocs/public"
```

This solved all my issues I believe.